# how to put bold math signs in textbf environment

Tags: bold, math-operators, boldmath, bm

hello guys i try to write C_max bold in a text bf environment but it does not work. Can u help me please? I al ready tried bm but it just works for the C not the max.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage[colorlinks= false, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{pgfgantt}
  \usepackage{bm}
    \begin{document}
   \textbf{\textit{Berechnung von $\bm{C_{\max}}$}}
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an alternative:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{\textit{Berechnung von $\boldsymbol{C_{\max}}$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: dont work with mathptmx

Comment: @MiloLi Thanks for your precise and informative feedback!

Comment: look in my mwe what i posted... there is no way to write bold math signs with mathptmx that is my problem :/  i just wanted to change my font into something bigger and sexier lookin you know instead of usin times new roman.... sorry for that non usable feedback before

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with `mathptmx`. With `newtx` which uses a `times` clone, you don't have this problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}%
 \usepackage[colorlinks= false, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{bm}

    \begin{document}

   \textbf{\textit{Berechnung von $\bm{C_{\max}}$}}

   \textit{Berechnung von ${C_{\max}}$}

   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but i need the mathptmx, if i change to the newtx, i got many errors as Option clash for package textcomp. is there another solution ?

Comment: Are you sure you need `textcomp`?

Comment: latex says that error but in my programm it shows me at \noindent text....

Comment: Anyway, `textcomp` has no option, so it must be something else. Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: it will destroy everything.... cuz its a thesis... and i dont know what to build in a mwe because i dont know where the mistake is... so it would be a very tooo long code you know . is there no other solution with mathptmx to write bold math signs @bernard?

Comment: or could you look over my thesis and my packages? on skype or somewhere ? that would be very awesome just 5 mins ?

Comment: i see that i cant write bold texts in matptmx... so im screwed but i love the font! can you mail me ?

Comment: @Milo Li: Unfortunately, it is explicitly described in `mathptmx.sty`: it has no bold math font (l. 60-65). This means that, even if you can use the bold times letters with`\mathbf`, you won't have bold  `symbols` to match them. There are commercial fonts which have bold math, but you have to pay for them. Do you find `TeX Gyre Termes` (on which `newtx` is based)  so different  from Adobe Times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50048/discussion-between-milo-li-and-bernard).